# Display All the Table Records in the same page without using horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabular

I have a huge table that I want to show it on my website. It has got 60 columns and as many as 2000 rows. Could you please guide me how can I represent these data in the webpage. Right now, I made a scrollbar horizontal and vertical in the webpage and reproduced all the data. It seems clumsy and awkward. This is my first venture in web development, so anyone could guide on simplifying this complexity, it will be great help for me. What I am looking forward is when the user wants a row of data from the table, all those cells should be visible in the same page without the need for a scroll.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: One option is to only display columns that are absolutely necessary for the user and provide a way to show columns that are missing as well. Also, depending on the data, you can provide an option to click an item and open it in it's own page where all data is visible

Comment: Grouped my columns and still it needs 25 columns. And as you said, can you help me where can i start with those changes in my code @Razvan

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery DataTables with Responsive plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) which will hide extra columns could be shown when necessary.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/default.html) for demonstration of displaying extra details in a collapsible child row.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/modal.html) for demonstration of displaying extra details in a modal window.